# Mock mysql in JEST testing gone wrong

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mysql2

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
require('iconv-lite').encodingExists('foo');


it('tests jest-mysql', () => {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        database: 'test'
    });

    connection.connect();
       
    connection.query(
        "CREATE TABLE users( Name varchar(45),Age int)",
        (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            console.log('results', results);
        }
    )
    connection.end();
});
```

i need to mock a database and check of a function enters the responses into the tables as expected i don't need the entire db schema to copied and tested, but just the tables with the required columns to be created and dropped after the tests are done.
i've tried an approach and don't know if that is the right one but this approch gives me an error i can't resolve.

the error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From index.test.js.

      at ClientHandshake.handshakeResult (node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/client_handshake.js:150:26)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:45:22)
      at Connection.handlePacket (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\index.test.js:12
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError: authSwitch.authSwitchRequest is not a function
    at ClientHandshake.handshakeResult (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\
lib\commands\client_handshake.js:155:22)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\lib\comm
ands\command.js:45:22)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\lib\conn
ection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connec
tion.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\lib\pa
cket_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Office\bulk-backend\beats-bulk-ave-claim-sqs-trigger\claims\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connectio
n.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  code: 'AUTH_SWITCH_PLUGIN_ERROR',
  fatal: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
require('iconv-lite').encodingExists('foo');



it('tests jest-mysql', async () => {

    var connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'abcd1234',
        database: 'test'
    });
       
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
    console.log(rows);
    console.log(fields);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.